# Process Builder's Input Stream never returns end of stream

Tags: java, linux, sh, inputstream, processbuilder

Please check this following code snippet i have written

```
List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>();
commandList.add("sh");
commandList.add(START_PGSQL_FILE_PATH);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
builder.directory(new File(BIN_DIRECTORY));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
line = br.readLine();
sb.append(line);
system.out.println(line);
}
system.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The line is printed always and it is printed until the sh file completed its process.But still the input stream waits.The same sh file when I run in console,it works fine and the process completes without waiting for any user input.

It doesn't happen always but it happens most of the time.So I just execute the code again and again until the point it goes to the next line of my code.

But why does this happen?Also what is the reason for the inputStream to wait though the sh file completed its process.

Comment: Have a look at [process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--). Should be placed after the loop where you read the output.

Comment: Yaa i have kept that too(forgot to write that line in the snippet)...but before that the print statement has to be printed.

Comment: Does you script use redirection to/from stdin/stderr? Is it working with a simple script, which does only print few llines?

Comment: As i said,sometimes it does work,but mostly it doesn't.As far as redirection,i think no bcoz the script is used to just start the pgsql db.